# Use pytest-mysql to build unit tests for SQL queries in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, mysql-python

I am building an app that runs several SQL queries in MySQL to get information. I have been searching online and I have found the `pytest-mysql` package (see [link][1]). However, I am struggling to understand the documentation and there are not yet many examples online on how to use this.

So I have installed MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu and I am using `pytest`. The way I am envisioning testing the functions that use SQL queries is by creating a temporary table with dummy data (I do not want to test on production data), run the test queries and compare the output with an expected output. Is this possible to do with the `pytest-mysql` package without interfering/accessing the production data?